# zoo::rollapply generates an error when applying a function from another package to a column of a dataframe

Tags: r, zoo, rollapply

Here's a miminal example:

`df_1 <- data. Frame( a = 1:10)`

I have no trouble computing a rolling mean on `a` using `zoo::rollapply`

```
zoo::rollapply(df_1$a, 5, "mean", fill = NA, align = "right")
 [1] NA NA NA NA  3  4  5  6  7  8
```

But if I try to do the same with the HodgesLehmann function in DescTools, I generate an error:

```
> zoo::rollapply(df_1$a, 5, "DescTools::HodgesLehmann", fill = NA, align = "right")
Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
  object 'DescTools::HodgesLehmann' of mode 'function' was not found
```

But i have no difficulty computing the Hodges Lehmann mean for `df_1$a`:

```
DescTools::HodgesLehmann(df_1$a)
[1] 5.5
```

What I am doing wrong, and how can I correct my error?

Sincerely and with many thanks in advance

Thomas Philips

Answer (score 2):

Remove the quotation marks around `DescTools::HodgesLehmann`:

```
zoo::rollapply(df_1$a, 5, DescTools::HodgesLehmann, fill = NA, align = "right")
```

You need to pass a function, not a character string.

It is surprising that `FUN = "mean"` works, but importantly `FUN = mean` works too. Perhaps `zoo::rollapply` has a few functions that it knows the name of.

Comment: Aha - it must know enough about a bunch of functions so that you can write the name with or without quotes so that I mistook the special case for the general case. Good lesson! Thanks

Comment: It does accept the function name as a character string but `DescTools::HodgesLehman` is an expression that evaluates to the function, not the name of the function.  Had we used `DescTools::"HodgesLehman"` it would have worked.

Comment: Gosh - it's even more subtle than I thought!

Answer (score 1):

Try setting as an anonymous function.

```
zoo::rollapply(df_1$a, 5, function(x) DescTools::HodgesLehmann(x), fill = NA, align = "right")

#
[1] NA NA NA NA  3  4  5  6  7  8
```

Comment: Works beautifully - thank you very much. Can you explain to me in layman's language why this works and why my earlier attempt did not?

Comment: You may want to take a look at the help text for the function. Here is an example they give.## rolling weekly sums (with some missing dates)
z <- zoo(1:11, as.Date("2016-03-09") + c(0:7, 9:10, 12))
weeksum <- function(z) sum(z[time(z) > max(time(z)) - 7])
zs <- rollapplyr(z, 7, weeksum, fill = NA, coredata = FALSE)
merge(value = z, weeksum = zs)